# unable to get output from logfstast to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, logstash

I am unable to get output from Logstash to Elasticsearch while running on localhost:9200. Keeping log in local path & created index & executing in a file called test.conf

```
input { 
  file { 
    path => "C:/logs/nginxAccess.log" 
    start_position => "beginning" } 
} 
filter { 
  date { 
   match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ] 
  } 
} 
output { 
  file { 
   path => "C:/output.log" 
  } 
  stdout { 
   codec => rubydebug 
  } 
}
```

> "122.164.121.231 - - [23/Nov/2015:07:19:54 -0500] "GET
>   /configs/config/thecelloserenades@gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 1135
>   "localhost/octoviz-auth/public/octoviz/admin/admin.html"; "Mozilla/5.0
>   (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0"

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Do you want to show Logstash output in the console?

Comment: I need logstash output either in a file ( like c:\temp\output.log or in elastic search in  index --  http://localhost:9200/test/_search ) i am having test .conf file i will run logstash -f test.conf also havig  log input file

Comment: can you post the configuration file for a start?

Comment: input {
  file {
    path => "C:/logs/nginxAccess.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
 date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}
output {
    file {
        path => "C:/output.log"
    }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  }

Comment: "122.164.121.231 - - [23/Nov/2015:07:19:54 -0500] "GET /configs/config/thecelloserenades@gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 1135 "http://localhost/octoviz-auth/public/octoviz/admin/admin.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0""

Comment: first comment = > conf file 2nd comment log file . kindly guide me as it is stretching too much time

Comment: 2018-05-29T15:16:15,867][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.i.m.p.TransportPutMappingAction] [node-1] failed to put mappings on indices [[[test/z1vJKSguRMG962-BTnvuOQ]]], type [doc]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rejecting mapping update to [test] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [doc, items]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:501) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:353) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]

Comment: DO i need too remove any log fields ?